# key-value pairs combining two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, key-value

I have the following two arrays:

```
const char[3] *Letters= {"one", "two", "three"}
const char[5] *Numbers= {"1", "2", "3","4", "5"}
```

How may I print a key-value pair such as:

```
("one" "1"), ("one", "2"), ("one", "3")......("two", "1"), ("two", "2")...
```

I'm trying to use a for-loop to perform this action:

```
for(i=0;i<3; i++){
  for(i=0;i<5; i++){
    printf("%s %s \n", Letters[i],Numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

The question is that my above approach is not working

Comment: your code needs separate index variables for the outer and inner loop, so try using 'j' for the inner loop, and earlier in the code, add 'int j;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use separate variable for inner `for` loop statement. Common one is `j`.

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible and less error prone approach would be using a sentinel, a stopper value: `NULL` instead of explicilty coding and reusing the arrays' sizes:

```
const char[] * letters= {"one", "two", "three", NULL}
const char[] * numbers= {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", NULL}

char * l = letters;

while (NULL != l)
{
  char * n = numbers;

  while (NULL != n)
  {
    printf("%s %s \n", l, n);
    ++n;
  }

  ++l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable in both the `for` loop. You should use another variable for your nested `for` loop. How about using `j` there.

---

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i, j;
    char Letters[3][10] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    char Numbers[5][3] = {"1", "2", "3","4", "5"};
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j<5; j++)
      {
        printf("%s %s \n", Letters[i], Numbers[j]);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
for(i=0;i<3; i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<5; j++)
  {
        printf("%s %s \n", Letters[i],Numbers[j]);
  }
}
```

Both of your `for`s are running on the same variable i , but you don't really want it to do so , so you need a separate variable (counter) for the second for.

then you will print it as you want.

Comment: @alk No idea , probably someone personally dislikes me :~